# Google sheets dynamic list using the FILTER function with dates?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a simple checkbook register on one sheet, then have monthly spreads where the data is separated out by that month. I've used =FILTER() before to automatically generate a list on a separate sheet based on the conditions set. But for some reason I'm struggling when it comes to dates.

Here's the function I'm trying to use (which isn't quite right)

```
=FILTER('Checkbook Register'!B14:J1000,TEXT('Checkbook Register'!B13:B1000, "mmmm")=B2)
```

B2 has the current month as a string December in this case.

The data I'm trying to copy to a another sheet as it's entered is in this format

| Date | No. | Description | Debit | Credit | Balance | Cleared |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11/20/2021 | # | Transact 1 | 1.00 |  | 6.00 | y |
| 12/1/2021 | # | Transact 2 | 1.00 |  | 5.00 | y |
| 12/1/2021 | # | Transact 3 | 1.00 |  | 4.00 | n |

What I'd like it to do is if the Date column matches the current month listed in B2 then add those transaction lines to the new sheet. I feel like I'm making this more complicated than it really is.

I've used this formula before to make the list if the checkbox is true

```
=FILTER(T5:X22,S5:S22=TRUE)
```

and loved the functionality of it. I thought something similar would be very useful in my personal budgeting spreadsheet rather than entering transactions on each individual monthly spread. I could track them on one main sheet and use the filter function to split them out.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was close! In case anyone uses this in the future, my ranges were one row off. ^-^

B14:J1000 and B13:B1000

```
=FILTER('Checkbook Register'!B14:J1000,TEXT('Checkbook Register'!B14:B1000, "mmmm")=B2)
```

After correcting, this worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

just in case B2 = December and B column contains empty cells use:

```
=FILTER('Checkbook Register'!B14:J, 
   TEXT('Checkbook Register'!B14:B, "mmmm")=B2, 
        'Checkbook Register'!B14:B<>"")
```